# How to handle two different callback functions in a component, one that updates state and the other that calls a function that uses that state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, react-state

I'm working on a game in which I need to check the collision of two objects, the "enemy" and the player. Everytime that the enemy moves, it runs a callback function where it passes its current position to the *handleCollision* function.

This handleCollision function uses the returned enemy position and the current player position (stored in state) to check if there was a collision.

The issue is that even though the player callback is setting the playerPosition state to the current position, when the enemy calls the handleCollision function, a value of (0,0) is passed as the player's position.

Code examples below:

GameState.tsx

```
export default function GameState() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const [enemies, setEnemies] = useState<Array<React.ReactNode>>([]);

  const [playerPosition, setPlayerPosition] = useState<Position>({
    xpos: 0,
    ypos: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setEnemies(createEnemies(1));
  }, []);

  function handleCollision(otherObject: Position) {

    if (checkCollision(playerPosition, otherObject)) {
      setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
    }
  }

  function createEnemies(numEnemies: number) {
    let enemies = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++) {
      enemies.push(
        <Enemies
          key={i}
          onPositionChange={(position: Position) => {
            handleCollision(position);
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    return enemies;
  }

  return (
    // Need to pass the score as a prop to the canvas element
    <Canvas>
      <ThePlayer
        onPositionChange={(position: Position) => {
          setPlayerPosition(position);
        }}
      />
      {enemies}
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

Emenies.tsx

```
export default function Enemies({ onPositionChange }) {
  const enemy = useRef(new Enemy());

  const [enemyPosition, setEnemyPosition]: Position = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      enemy.current.move();
      const newPosition = enemy.current.getPos();
      setEnemyPosition(enemy.current.getPos());
      onPositionChange(newPosition);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)) + 200;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="enemy"
      style={{
        top: `${enemy.current.posy}px`,
        left: `${enemy.current.posx}px`,
        transform: `rotate(${enemy.current.direction}deg)`,
      }}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

Player.tsx

```
export default function ThePlayer({ onPositionChange }) {
  const player = new Player();

  const [xpos, setXpos] = useState(player.getPos().posx);
  const [ypos, setYpos] = useState(player.getPos().posy);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => move(e);
    onPositionChange({ xpos, ypos }); // Initialize position
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [ypos, xpos]);

  function move(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newPosX = xpos;
    let newPosY = ypos;
    switch (e.key) {
      case "ArrowUp":
        if (ypos - player.speed <= 0) {
          newPosY = window.innerHeight - 20;
        } else {
          newPosY -= player.speed;
        }
        break;

      case "ArrowDown":
        if (ypos + player.speed >= window.innerHeight) {
          newPosY = 0;
        } else {
          newPosY += player.speed;
        }
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
        if (xpos - player.speed <= 0) {
          newPosX = window.innerWidth - 20;
        } else {
          newPosX -= player.speed;
        }
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
        if (xpos + player.speed >= window.innerWidth) {
          newPosX = 0;
        } else {
          newPosX += player.speed;
        }
        break;

      case " ":
        //Handle spacebar logic
        console.log("Spacebar Pressed!");
        break;

      default:
        console.log("Not a valid action key!");
    }
    // console.log("Player Position Updated:", { xpos: newPosX, ypos: newPosY });
    setXpos(newPosX);
    setYpos(newPosY);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="player"
      style={{ top: `${ypos}px`, left: `${xpos}px` }}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

I've tried console logging within the different components and it seems that the player component is actually passing the correct position to the callback function. Same thing with the enemy's position.

I think that the issue exists somewhere in the GameState.tsx file as the initial state of playerPosition stays at (0,0) and subsequently this is the value that is passed when the checkCollision function is called within the handleCollison function.

If I change the initial values for the playerPosition state, these get passed as well.